# EntityFramework Core automatic migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, microsoft-identity-web

In my project I have 2 databases: one is my custom database and the other one is `ApplicationDbContext` that `Microsoft Identity` gives me.

In my `Startup.cs` I have this code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
        ApplicationDbContext db, MyContext dbPSC)
{
     // ...

    db.Database.EnsureCreated();
    db.Database.Migrate();

    dbPSC.Database.EnsureCreated();
    dbPSC.Database.Migrate();
}
```

I don't know when there is a migration to migrate, right? Then, I have 2 errors:

- the migration for `ApplicationDbContext` raises an error every time the application starts apart from the first time
- the migration for my context seems fine

What is the best practise to use? Is it necessary to call the migration for `ApplicationDbContext`?

### Update

I have removed the `Migration` folder. Then, changed the `Startup.cs` like

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
        ApplicationDbContext db, MyContext dbPSC)
{
     // ...

    db.Database.EnsureCreated();
    dbPSC.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

but when the application starts, it doesn't create any tables at all. `AuditDbContext` is because I use [Audit.net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/)

```
public class MyContext : AuditDbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AuditMessage> Audit_Messages { get; set; }

    #region Common Tables
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AuditCountry> Audit_Countries { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Seed
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Seed();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

### Update #2

I tried another solution but it doesn't work. The solution is to use `RelationalDatabaseCreator` like the following code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,
        ApplicationDbContext db, MyContext dbPSC)
{
     // ...

    db.Database.EnsureCreated();
    dbPSC.Database.EnsureCreated();
    RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator = 
     (RelationalDatabaseCreator)context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
    databaseCreator.CreateTables();
}
```

As the `Migrate()`, the first time the app runs it creates the tables but the second time it raises an error because the tables are already exist in the database.

Comment: What specific error do you see? And are you using MS SQL databases? Because some migrations tend to fail on SqLite for example. Btw, `EnsureCreated()` doesn't just create the DB; it also creates the whole DB schema based on the current state of the models (ignoring the migrations).

Comment: I'm using MSSQL. I don't understand when I have to call the migration. Is there a way to detect if the application needs to run the migration?

Comment: I updated the answer with that; hopefully it's useful. Feel free to add more questions; I type fast. :)

Comment: I've read the updates in the question, but the problem is obvious. `EnsureCreated` doesn't do anything if the database already exists. And when you're using `RelationalDatabaseCreator.CreateTables()` (which btw explicitly not advised to use in application code by the docs), it expects not to have tables in the database (which is also mentioned in the docs). The reason you're having these problems is frankly that you're using EF Core in weird ways. :) But if you insist using it like this, you could probably just ignore the exception thrown by `CreateTables()` with an empty try/catch.

Comment: What does weird ways mean? EF Core has to create the tables when the application starts without errors.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is most likely that you're calling `EnsureCreated()`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-5.0):

> Note that this API does not use migrations to create the database. **In addition, the database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations.** If you are targeting a relational database and using migrations, you can use the DbContext.Database.Migrate() method to ensure the database is **created and all migrations are applied**.

So, it's enough to call `Migrate()`. But I don't blame you, because `EnsureCreated()` is definitely a misleading method name. It does a lot, since it also creates the DB schema that is not even based on migrations, but on the current state of the entities.

**But** if you don't want to use migrations for Identity context (because you don't extend those entities in any way), then the reverse is true: You don't need to call `Migrate()`, and calling `EnsureCreated()` is enough to make sure that the schema is created the first time.

#### Is calling `Migrate()` necessary?

As for what's best practice: Some developers don't like to call `Migrate()` at all from code, because they believe that DB schema operations like that should be more controlled (I'm sure you know that you can execute db update from CLI too). It depends on your requirements I guess.

And with respect to this specific case on having a separate database for Identity tables: They most likely will never change, and they especially won't create a migration by themselves. So I'd say that calling `Migrate()` on it is unnecessary, besides the fact that it can create and migrate the database if it didn't exist (so it might be useful to keep for that reason; if you're using migrations for that context to begin with).

#### Detecting whether migration is needed

You can use `context.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync()` to check if migration is needed. How it's done is that the DB has an `EFMigrationsHistory` table that stores the Id of the applied migrations, which can be compared to the migrations files in your solution.

But I think most developers don't call this `GetPendingMigrationsAsync()` (or the sync version, for that matter), because you can just call `Migrate()`, and if the DB is already updated, no harm is done.

#### Clarifying Migrations vs `EnsureCreated`

I'm not sure how much have you worked with EF, so chances are this is obvious. But `Migrate()` is used when you already created migrations with e.g. `dotnet ef migrations add <migrationname>`, which is a way to incrementally alter the database schema with a code-first approach.

But if you don't use migrations at all, you have a very simple schema that won't be needed to be altered incrementally with migrations, and you just want to make sure that the DB exists with a schema, then use only `EnsureCreated()`, and don't use `Migrate()`.

The issue is that if you happen to change your entities, `EnsureCreated()` won't update the database; if the database already exists, it does nothing. So you'd have to call `EnsureDeleted()` followed by `EnsureCreated()` to achieve an up-to-date DB schema without migrations. Which obviously involves losing all your data. This is why migrations are useful. `EnsureCreated()` is mostly used for e.g. integration testing.

---

Btw, you can use the same DB context for your own tables and Identity; I'd hazard  to say that's the 'normal' way of working with EF. Of course you could have your specific reasons for separating I suppose.

Comment: Is this for `Microsoft.Identity`?

Comment: It's not dependent on Identity. Those are also just normal DbSets in a normal DbContext.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use both  `db.Database.EnsureCreated();` and `db.Database.Migrate();`
You need to use `db.Database.EnsureCreated();` when you don't have migrations enabled in your application. If you have migrations enabled then only use `db.Database.Migrate();` and that would be enough.

But if you don't enable migrations then on every change you have to re create your db. Because "EnsureCreated" only verifies if the db already exists. So better to enable Migrations.

So if you don't want to change anything in ApplicationDbContext so you can use `db.Database.EnsureCreated();` but if you want to change something or may be you want to add more fields in AspNetUsers etc then you should enable migrations and use `db.Database.Migrate();`

Btw you can also add your custom tables in ApplicationDbContext if you want.

Comment: Then, I can remove the migration files, disabled the migration and use only `db.Database.Migrate();`. How can I disable a migration?

Comment: I think you mean "use only db.Database.EnsureCreated();". So for that just delete the migration files and also MigrationHistory table from db. That would be enough

Answer (score 1):

Based on the replies you guys sent to me, my solution is to use migration. In the `Startup.cs` I added those lines of code (dbPSC is a `DbContext`)

```
dbPSC.Database.EnsureCreated();
if (dbPSC.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
    dbPSC.Database.Migrate();
```